# Как выглядит раскрутка групп в социальных сетях изнутри?

Tags: соцсети

У меня не совсем обычный вопрос. Сейчас очень популярна услуга раскрутки (или накрутки?) Вашей группы или паблика (или просто накрутка количества пользователей?) в таких социальных сетях как twitter, facebook, instagram, Вконтакте, Одноклассники, YouTube, Google+ и так далее.

Как нагоняют в группы ботов еще более-менее понятно... Скорее всего с помощью спец. ПО. Если да, то какого ПО?

Однако мне не совсем понятно как приводят в группу настоящих людей? Например: 50 долларов = 1000 человек, нужно же привести 1000 человек на 50 долларов и еще что-то заработать. Как это делается? Кто в курсе?

Заранее спасибо, за ответы.

Comment: Чтобы было понятие про, что я тут глаголю - вот пример услуги (не реклама) - http://www.kharkovforum.com/showthread.php?t=2679679

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Биржи лайков - пользователю платят какой-нибудь `.01`¢ за каждый лайк в требуемой группе.
2. Кросспостинг -  обращаешься в группу покрупнее, та делает репост из твоей группы, а ты делаешь репост из его. Обоим кроссреклама.
3. Проплаченные (ре)посты - платишь уже раскрученной группе, та пишет пост о том какая твоя группа интересная и помещает ссылку.
4. Репост на стену - создаётся аккаунт с большим количеством друзей и вуаля.
5. Акции с рандомом - `репостни пост, поставь лайк и получи возможность бесплатно выиграть что-нибудь`.
6. Ссылка на улице. Типичный пример - ссылка на двери ресторана.
7. Традиционные рекламные методики

Встаёт вопрос об эффективности, но это уже другая история.